# Node.js I need a single script to combine tsc build watch with nodemon

Tags: node.js, typescript, package.json, npm-scripts, npm-start

I currently have two scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p . -w",
    "watchjs": "nodemon dist/index.js"
}
```

And I need two terminals one for build one for watchjs, I want to combine these two scripts into a single script so that it automatically builds after changes have been detected and runs it after build!

I tried something like:

```
"start": "tsc -p . -w && node dist/index.js",
```

But obviously

```
tsc -w
```

Never ends therefore I cannot call a command directly after a build has been completed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose your system is Windows (for below solution you need **concurrently** package as a devDependency)

Edited for better solution :

```
"build:w": "tsc -w",
"start": "nodemon ./build/index.js",
"dev": "concurrently  \"npm:build:w\" \"npm:start\""
```

> **npm run dev**

good luck !

Answer (score 1):

you can use also the `tsc-watch` utility, this helps to prevent any delay or `nodemon` running before the `tsc` completes running:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node ./dist/index.js\""
  }
}
```

> This saves you from using `nodemon` also, running the node command in each compile.